# Convert PKCS12 certificate to byte[] using Powershell

Tags: powershell, pkcs#12

I am trying to import a PKCS12 certificate to an identity management tool using APIs.

Is there a way to convert PKCS12 to byte[] using powershell. I want to give this value to my api so as to configure the application.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
[byte[]]$a = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("c:\cert.pfx")

write $a
```